# React Native BackHandler issue with react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am making an app with RN and have used react-navigation, I am stuck with BackHandler and don't know how to handle it. I have a normal structure as follows -
1. Splash Screen
2. Login Screen
3. Home screen with Drawer menu
4. Notification Screen
The flow is splash will be loaded and will check if user is logged in or not, if he is then Home screen will be the first else Login will be the one.

If I press back from Login it should exit the app and same with the home screen, and if I go back from Notification screen it should navigate to Homescreen.

I have tried following method to achieve this, but was unable to make it -
1. Have handled BackHandler in all components and have written exit in home and login with an Alert asking to really want to exit or not, but when I move to notification screen and press device back button, the back method in home screen gets overriden and doesn't work the way I want.
2. Added BackHandler in root component and made the thing based on the current route parameter, have used redux with react-navigation, but it also didn't helped me.

Please help me what is the best method to achieve what I want, I am really stuck

Answer (score 0):

You should create 2 stack navigators like this:

1. AuthNavigator: Login
2. MainNavigator: Home -> Notification

When open Splash Screen, you will check user logged in or not:

- If no, open AuthNavigator: `this.props.navigation.dispatch(AuthNavigator);`
  After login success, you need to reset back stack and navigate to MainNavigator
- If yes, open MainNavigator: `this.props.navigation.dispatch(MainNavigator);`